# How to get partition type by kernel32 API?

Tags: kernel32

Is there a kernel32 API can help us to detect the partition type ( Primary/Logical ) ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think these links may be of interest:

Example code:
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?312464-Windows-SDK-File-System-How-to-get-information-about-a-partition

Microsoft docs:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139547

Comment: thanks...but I had already try this api
It can display 1. szVolumeName, sizeof VolumeName, dwSerialNumber,            &dwMaxFileNameLength,
                          &dwFileSystemFlags,
                          szFileSystemName,
                          sizeof(szFileSystemName)

Comment: Ahh, ok. I thought it might at least be a good place to start.
I did some more digging and found this as well. Maybe not exactly what you want but a step in the right direction:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365180(v=vs.85)